$G$ finite group, $H$ normal subgroup, $P$ Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, then $G = HN_G(P)$
This is related to: This question
Consider the same premise. $G$ a finite group, $H$ normal in $G$, and $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. Then the claim is $G = HN_G(P)$. I want to ask if my attempt may lead anywhere:

Clearly, $HN_G(P) \subseteq G$. So it suffices to show $|G| = |HN_G(P)|$.
We know that $$|HN_G(P)| = \frac{|H||N_G(P)|}{|H \cap N_G(P)|} = \frac{|H||N_G(P)|}{|N_H(P)|}$$
So it suffices to show that $\frac{|H|}{|N_H(P)|} = \frac{|G|}{|N_G(P)|}$, or perhaps $\frac{|N_G(P)|}{|N_H(P)|} = [G:H]$. We know $\frac{|H|}{|N_H(P)|} \equiv 1 \mod p$ by Sylow (+ Orbit-Stablizer theorem).

Here is where I’m stuck, I know by Sylow, since $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$, it is contained in some $Q$ Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. So acting on $P$ by conjugation will permute $P$ to another $p$-subgroup of some $Q’\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$. Is there anything I can say about $\frac{|G|}{|N_G(P)|}$ that could progress this argument?

If you assume $P\le H$, then $[G:N_G(P)]=[H:N_H(P)]$ follows from the orbit-stabilizer theorem and the fact $H\lhd G$. Can you see this implies your case?

Oh sorry I think I misread your question. If $P$ is just an arbitrary Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, then it is not always true that $G=HN_G(P)$.

@SteveD that’s my mistake! $P$ is assumed to be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. Following your previous comment, I was able to show that the orbit of $H$ acting on $N_H(P)$ and $G$ acting on $N_G(P)$ are in bijection, thus the two indices are equal. Which gives me my desired $\frac{|H|}{|N_H(P)|} = \frac{|G|}{|N_G(P)|}$.

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$There is a basic result in the theory of group actions that states the following.

Let $G$ be a group acting on the set $\Omega$. Suppose $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ that acts transitively on $\Omega$. Then for every $\alpha \in \Omega$ we have $G = H G_{\alpha}$, where $G_{\alpha} = \Set{ g \in G : g \alpha = \alpha }$ is the stabiliser of $\alpha$ in $G$.

The proof is straightforward. Given an arbitrary $g \in G$, since $H$ acts transitively there is $h \in H$ such that $g \alpha = h \alpha$. Hence $h^{-1} g = s \in G_{\alpha}$, and $g = h s$.
The result you are considering is the special case when $\Omega$ is the set of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$, on which $G$ acts by conjugation, as $H$ is normal in $G$.

Let $g\in G$. Then $gPg^{-1}\subseteq gHg^{-1} =H$, since $H$ is normal; so $gPg^{-1}$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. Therefore, there exists $h\in H$ s.t. $gPg^{-1}=hPh^{-1}$, and in particular $h^{-1}g\in N_G(P)$, and hence $g\in hN_G(P) \subseteq HN_G(P)$.
This proves $G\subseteq HN_G(P)$. The other inclusion is immediate.
